# Users in android

Tags: android

I was woundering if theres any way to program an android smartphone to work with users like windows works, when each user has it's own desktop meaning it's own apps and it's own configurations?

any help would be good for me i'm kind of lost here

Comment: Android have only one user its mobile OS not Computer OS. There is need of this concept when multiple user use computer but in mobile i don't think we can create multiple user like computer os do.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple User support was unofficially added in 4.1, and was made public and [enabled on tablets in 4.2](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers).